# Using delimiters cuts out data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Another python/pandas novice question. I'm attempting to read in a .txt file separated by spaces, but as the number of headers does not match the number of columns of data, it cuts off all data after the headers have finished. I have been using pandas for the data analysis and the following code to define the data.

`dfBondAng = pd.read_csv(fileBondAng, delimiter = '\s+')`

The issue is that each dfBondAng file will have a varying amount of rows (this comes from the initial software), so it needs to be applicable for x number of columns in order to automate it.

Thanks!

EDIT: Example datas

```
# theta[deg.]       Ow-Mg1-Ow                     Ow-Mg1-O1                     O1-Mg1-O1                 
  0.5000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1500000E+01  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2500000E+01  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.3500000E+01  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.4500000E+01  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.5500000E+01  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.6500000E+01  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.7500000E+01  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.8500000E+01  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.9500000E+01  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1050000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1150000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1250000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1350000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1450000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1550000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1650000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1750000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1850000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1950000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2050000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2150000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2250000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2350000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2450000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2550000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2650000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2750000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2850000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.2950000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.3050000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.3150000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.3250000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.3350000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.3450000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.3550000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.3650000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.3750000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.3850000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.3950000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.4050000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.4150000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.4250000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.4350000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.4450000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.4550000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.4650000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.4750000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.4850000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.4950000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.5050000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.5150000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.5250000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.5350000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.5450000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.5550000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.5650000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.5750000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.2025161E-04  0.9696107E-04  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.5850000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.1310340E-06  0.7486163E-05  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.5950000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.1403245E-06  0.8016935E-05  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.6050000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.1961406E-04  0.9391209E-04  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.6150000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.2569801E-06  0.1038048E-04  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.6250000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.3611679E-04  0.1198399E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.6350000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.5313588E-04  0.1836620E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.6450000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.7976898E-03  0.1930286E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.6550000E+02  0.5317045E-07  0.3037704E-05  0.7722053E-03  0.2029192E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.6650000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.7888316E-03  0.2295496E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.6750000E+02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.7305678E-03  0.2501888E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.6850000E+02  0.6507251E-05  0.3103798E-04  0.1451741E-03  0.3944754E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.6950000E+02  0.2591255E-03  0.1171214E-03  0.8738873E-03  0.1818416E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.7050000E+02  0.1225288E-04  0.4058491E-04  0.1276275E-02  0.1751907E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.7150000E+02  0.1405319E-03  0.4355279E-04  0.1341747E-02  0.5241247E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.7250000E+02  0.1520223E-03  0.4379986E-04  0.3145312E-02  0.5058877E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.7350000E+02  0.3027820E-03  0.7551111E-04  0.3958120E-02  0.4977963E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.7450000E+02  0.4454035E-03  0.8121450E-04  0.3795884E-02  0.5950336E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.7550000E+02  0.4804031E-03  0.1790630E-03  0.3831044E-02  0.1499826E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.7650000E+02  0.6352953E-03  0.8904549E-04  0.6697144E-02  0.1051770E-02  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.7750000E+02  0.1149526E-02  0.2321817E-03  0.7857731E-02  0.3501871E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.7850000E+02  0.2811136E-02  0.1239901E-03  0.8533218E-02  0.5791503E-03  0.1334189E-03  0.6412391E-03
  0.7950000E+02  0.3121748E-02  0.1736030E-03  0.1060008E-01  0.9195214E-03  0.3996801E-02  0.1805632E-02
  0.8050000E+02  0.5243878E-02  0.2660869E-03  0.1245178E-01  0.1014363E-02  0.3186337E-05  0.1288465E-03
  0.8150000E+02  0.6566220E-02  0.5057529E-03  0.1003692E-01  0.1835264E-02  0.4419164E-02  0.2059760E-02
  0.8250000E+02  0.1122602E-01  0.6979614E-03  0.1384838E-01  0.1393543E-02  0.4170304E-03  0.1367588E-02
  0.8350000E+02  0.1290338E-01  0.4585941E-03  0.1658986E-01  0.1183979E-02  0.7663317E-03  0.2222837E-02
  0.8450000E+02  0.1510847E-01  0.4385544E-03  0.1832649E-01  0.1540598E-02  0.4177309E-02  0.1599111E-02
  0.8550000E+02  0.1695085E-01  0.1233983E-02  0.2077008E-01  0.1880771E-02  0.2407452E-03  0.1148476E-02
  0.8650000E+02  0.1807026E-01  0.9922074E-03  0.2018253E-01  0.1569724E-02  0.6419220E-03  0.2202895E-02
  0.8750000E+02  0.1934961E-01  0.8083029E-03  0.2036045E-01  0.1160181E-02  0.4419812E-02  0.1410101E-02
  0.8850000E+02  0.2018336E-01  0.7850712E-03  0.1856933E-01  0.7626230E-03  0.4546096E-02  0.1696067E-02
  0.8950000E+02  0.1949824E-01  0.4941363E-03  0.1921365E-01  0.9194272E-03  0.1179401E-02  0.2861241E-02
  0.9050000E+02  0.1839275E-01  0.7668759E-03  0.1454549E-01  0.2005756E-02  0.1313354E-01  0.2622133E-02
  0.9150000E+02  0.1963071E-01  0.1600845E-02  0.1521793E-01  0.1408426E-02  0.1642956E-01  0.5831200E-02
  0.9250000E+02  0.1605915E-01  0.8001684E-03  0.1729483E-01  0.3481080E-03  0.1312551E-01  0.2917862E-02
  0.9350000E+02  0.1264932E-01  0.5503618E-03  0.1151031E-01  0.9571944E-03  0.1821357E-01  0.3607142E-02
  0.9450000E+02  0.1111558E-01  0.3514561E-03  0.1232203E-01  0.1477856E-02  0.1051338E-01  0.2535704E-02
  0.9550000E+02  0.1085368E-01  0.4139388E-03  0.1217712E-01  0.6078653E-03  0.1386622E-01  0.2594813E-02
  0.9650000E+02  0.6948029E-02  0.4348595E-03  0.8385060E-02  0.7359994E-03  0.5868551E-02  0.3052516E-02
  0.9750000E+02  0.8583306E-02  0.9983362E-03  0.1157779E-01  0.1530569E-02  0.1809455E-01  0.5859857E-02
  0.9850000E+02  0.6049289E-02  0.1556098E-03  0.6002768E-02  0.1382208E-02  0.5539122E-02  0.2327155E-02
  0.9950000E+02  0.4396019E-02  0.1701783E-03  0.8031080E-02  0.4563646E-03  0.7930396E-02  0.7662517E-02
  0.1005000E+03  0.4747306E-02  0.5404836E-03  0.5725235E-02  0.8569359E-03  0.9941644E-02  0.2765725E-02
  0.1015000E+03  0.2333225E-02  0.2823838E-03  0.4627071E-02  0.4941690E-03  0.1347445E-01  0.3140442E-02
  0.1025000E+03  0.2232520E-02  0.3285337E-03  0.4571554E-02  0.6239323E-03  0.1002063E-01  0.4377526E-02
  0.1035000E+03  0.2130698E-02  0.1758839E-03  0.4378926E-02  0.4710147E-03  0.1685715E-01  0.6085184E-02
  0.1045000E+03  0.1530198E-02  0.1011099E-03  0.3494214E-02  0.6893884E-03  0.1014216E-01  0.3828187E-02
  0.1055000E+03  0.1229167E-02  0.1633027E-03  0.2917007E-02  0.4709238E-03  0.1375168E-01  0.2917328E-02
  0.1065000E+03  0.1016582E-02  0.1331658E-03  0.2404521E-02  0.3439842E-03  0.5517128E-02  0.2437346E-02
  0.1075000E+03  0.1116987E-02  0.2585196E-03  0.2689888E-02  0.4525154E-03  0.9191249E-02  0.1694553E-02
  0.1085000E+03  0.8744136E-03  0.1495674E-03  0.1940698E-02  0.3622314E-03  0.4083873E-03  0.1429582E-02
  0.1095000E+03  0.3453728E-03  0.1048904E-03  0.8340974E-03  0.1790357E-03  0.5672290E-02  0.3999352E-02
  0.1105000E+03  0.5747511E-03  0.1404293E-03  0.9140612E-03  0.4442014E-03  0.4721251E-02  0.1490861E-02
  0.1115000E+03  0.3186053E-03  0.5492629E-04  0.1859090E-02  0.4773276E-03  0.8082997E-03  0.2370672E-02
  0.1125000E+03  0.1944948E-04  0.5169963E-04  0.1950874E-03  0.4734729E-03  0.4717755E-02  0.1449792E-02
  0.1135000E+03  0.2635851E-04  0.8667466E-04  0.1613605E-03  0.4123631E-03  0.2587598E-03  0.1215077E-02
  0.1145000E+03  0.1666549E-03  0.1067844E-03  0.8639336E-03  0.1665121E-03  0.4716013E-02  0.1507895E-02
  0.1155000E+03  0.1965083E-04  0.9251900E-04  0.3900193E-03  0.1210651E-03  0.4713844E-03  0.1559453E-02
  0.1165000E+03  0.2628786E-04  0.7406985E-04  0.7675498E-03  0.2497128E-03  0.6021374E-03  0.1621073E-02
  0.1175000E+03  0.7186061E-05  0.3392851E-04  0.1190716E-02  0.2626476E-03  0.1166076E-04  0.2870107E-03
  0.1185000E+03  0.2729706E-04  0.8983068E-04  0.3825483E-03  0.1463382E-03  0.9192071E-02  0.3644045E-02
  0.1195000E+03  0.2926927E-03  0.1013684E-03  0.5611545E-04  0.1481324E-03  0.2349019E-03  0.1112176E-02
  0.1205000E+03  0.1479275E-03  0.5660447E-04  0.5728511E-04  0.1506261E-03  0.5106467E-02  0.1599417E-02
  0.1215000E+03  0.2761906E-04  0.9088585E-04  0.3859556E-04  0.1266941E-03  0.7125913E-03  0.2494674E-02
  0.1225000E+03  0.1577838E-03  0.6669151E-04  0.5961339E-04  0.2103881E-03  0.4796129E-03  0.2298378E-02
  0.1235000E+03  0.1528361E-03  0.5844699E-04  0.3834195E-03  0.1731793E-03  0.5068965E-03  0.1677187E-02
  0.1245000E+03  0.7678785E-05  0.3581936E-04  0.4473005E-03  0.9707041E-04  0.6942089E-05  0.1990725E-03
  0.1255000E+03  0.7452655E-05  0.3528231E-04  0.4127448E-03  0.1581427E-03  0.3246903E-05  0.1316672E-03
  0.1265000E+03  0.1652997E-03  0.5068813E-04  0.4365320E-03  0.1338191E-03  0.2777141E-03  0.1322198E-02
  0.1275000E+03  0.1445377E-04  0.4776769E-04  0.2073924E-04  0.9745824E-04  0.1656942E-03  0.7951782E-03
  0.1285000E+03  0.1773926E-03  0.3855829E-04  0.8447243E-04  0.2373026E-03  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00
  0.1295000E+03  0.1954512E-03  0.8381125E-04  0.4140741E-03  0.1870649E-03  0.5090985E-02  0.2302443E-02
  0.1305000E+03  0.7869909E-05  0.3727385E-04  0.4562997E-06  0.1505331E-04  0.2164415E-05  0.1236559E-03
  0.1315000E+03  0.1701663E-03  0.6530085E-04  0.3106091E-06  0.1255586E-04  0.2002628E-05  0.1144130E-03
  0.1325000E+03  0.1598846E-04  0.7547652E-04  0.4308771E-04  0.2047030E-03  0.2069384E-05  0.1182264E-03
  0.1335000E+03  0.2075805E-03  0.4007359E-04  0.4851301E-03  0.1484812E-03  0.4099802E-05  0.1656104E-03
  0.1345000E+03  0.5191302E-03  0.2146500E-03  0.1163919E-03  0.3650947E-03  0.1022174E-04  0.3579062E-03
  0.1355000E+03  0.2245296E-03  0.1310396E-03  0.4560119E-03  0.2057878E-03  0.6084574E-02  0.1919286E-02
  0.1365000E+03  0.2024047E-03  0.1115572E-03  0.6978163E-04  0.1833349E-03  0.6796756E-05  0.2244399E-03
  0.1375000E+03  0.2552633E-04  0.1200223E-03  0.7026846E-04  0.3344742E-03  0.6016289E-02  0.2351180E-02
  0.1385000E+03  0.1771734E-04  0.5840175E-04  0.1148688E-05  0.2925097E-04  0.9785595E-03  0.3456387E-02
  0.1395000E+03  0.3580779E-04  0.1184256E-03  0.5188535E-03  0.1981931E-03  0.6288416E-03  0.2067676E-02
  0.1405000E+03  0.2099577E-03  0.6423095E-04  0.5030562E-03  0.2267860E-03  0.8682875E-05  0.2932477E-03
  0.1415000E+03  0.1935944E-04  0.6378098E-04  0.5368814E-04  0.1770743E-03  0.6670070E-02  0.2554946E-02
  0.1425000E+03  0.1037345E-04  0.4812853E-04  0.1905742E-03  0.5510187E-03  0.3462875E-03  0.1615428E-02
  0.1435000E+03  0.2145855E-03  0.8206420E-04  0.5588988E-04  0.1842231E-03  0.7420222E-02  0.2340228E-02
  0.1445000E+03  0.2098929E-03  0.9438898E-04  0.8698025E-04  0.3062762E-03  0.5798453E-03  0.1956869E-02
  0.1455000E+03  0.3180027E-04  0.1098189E-03  0.6776749E-03  0.1952964E-03  0.6382853E-05  0.2305901E-03
  0.1465000E+03  0.2521933E-03  0.5421493E-04  0.7237346E-03  0.2474144E-03  0.1499787E-01  0.5106275E-02
  0.1475000E+03  0.4955746E-03  0.1518981E-03  0.1279801E-02  0.3612644E-03  0.8703836E-03  0.2902084E-02
  0.1485000E+03  0.2775456E-03  0.1361205E-03  0.7654516E-03  0.3438716E-03  0.1550860E-02  0.5107564E-02
  0.1495000E+03  0.5359320E-03  0.1300893E-03  0.6852884E-04  0.2246780E-03  0.2089338E-02  0.7146765E-02
  0.1505000E+03  0.3616593E-04  0.9524190E-04  0.1008989E-03  0.3526694E-03  0.4188337E-03  0.1990261E-02
  0.1515000E+03  0.7355902E-04  0.1725935E-03  0.2115611E-02  0.7328998E-03  0.2210066E-04  0.5406708E-03
  0.1525000E+03  0.3025993E-03  0.1115937E-03  0.1522840E-02  0.3976211E-03  0.9233525E-02  0.2917843E-02
  0.1535000E+03  0.3378273E-03  0.1104626E-03  0.8970099E-03  0.3102763E-03  0.5100417E-03  0.2424655E-02
  0.1545000E+03  0.4188527E-03  0.2303440E-03  0.1913846E-03  0.5264399E-03  0.4753158E-03  0.2250166E-02
  0.1555000E+03  0.4063155E-03  0.2649390E-03  0.1118232E-02  0.6265645E-03  0.9983370E-02  0.3802577E-02
  0.1565000E+03  0.8583060E-03  0.3824924E-03  0.3095688E-02  0.5921519E-03  0.5206720E-03  0.2473958E-02
  0.1575000E+03  0.1426306E-02  0.3245711E-03  0.3686439E-02  0.9072293E-03  0.6044605E-03  0.2838162E-02
  0.1585000E+03  0.2216597E-02  0.4340307E-03  0.4987915E-02  0.7972356E-03  0.2381388E-01  0.5932991E-02
  0.1595000E+03  0.1863045E-02  0.5752352E-03  0.5232140E-02  0.1056825E-02  0.4107684E-03  0.1975044E-02
  0.1605000E+03  0.2883974E-02  0.5176784E-03  0.3807868E-02  0.8192922E-03  0.1867449E-02  0.6603516E-02
  0.1615000E+03  0.5576034E-02  0.9887831E-03  0.6776329E-02  0.1855395E-02  0.1545665E-01  0.3471544E-02
  0.1625000E+03  0.2464951E-02  0.1273845E-02  0.1220881E-01  0.1470700E-02  0.1611966E-01  0.5289689E-02
  0.1635000E+03  0.6091817E-02  0.3957927E-03  0.1098119E-01  0.1721623E-02  0.5408094E-02  0.1320408E-01
  0.1645000E+03  0.7577341E-02  0.1188537E-02  0.1179055E-01  0.3932926E-02  0.1639934E-01  0.7646515E-02
  0.1655000E+03  0.1148746E-01  0.1116402E-02  0.1418785E-01  0.1971286E-02  0.5168341E-01  0.1459463E-01
  0.1665000E+03  0.1317991E-01  0.5387230E-03  0.1396933E-01  0.1894750E-02  0.3847411E-01  0.6183106E-02
  0.1675000E+03  0.1644396E-01  0.1407136E-02  0.2304986E-01  0.1163787E-02  0.4375942E-01  0.8680771E-02
  0.1685000E+03  0.1846749E-01  0.1385319E-02  0.3488287E-01  0.4112486E-02  0.3940308E-02  0.9086032E-02
  0.1695000E+03  0.2390270E-01  0.2364652E-02  0.3604764E-01  0.4919499E-02  0.8937212E-01  0.3241187E-01
  0.1705000E+03  0.3585579E-01  0.3296026E-02  0.2394210E-01  0.2450588E-02  0.3254006E-01  0.1762093E-01
  0.1715000E+03  0.4189049E-01  0.4040896E-02  0.3624225E-01  0.1619123E-02  0.5542041E-02  0.1827754E-01
  0.1725000E+03  0.4509095E-01  0.2771432E-02  0.3482942E-01  0.4176145E-02  0.6648353E-01  0.2022181E-01
  0.1735000E+03  0.4346194E-01  0.2319244E-02  0.5388298E-01  0.8851916E-02  0.4770917E-01  0.2106666E-01
  0.1745000E+03  0.5686841E-01  0.3497622E-02  0.3713161E-01  0.4695580E-02  0.4314588E-01  0.1653445E-01
  0.1755000E+03  0.8284099E-01  0.7121739E-02  0.4432051E-01  0.4930889E-02  0.5628474E-01  0.1776708E-01
  0.1765000E+03  0.6046562E-01  0.4729013E-02  0.3840926E-01  0.1596064E-01  0.7096329E-01  0.3131214E-01
  0.1775000E+03  0.8774068E-01  0.5058556E-02  0.7484148E-01  0.1075412E-01  0.4791336E-02  0.2259683E-01
  0.1785000E+03  0.5246031E-01  0.1845189E-01  0.3197640E-01  0.7152270E-02  0.9199019E-04  0.5255532E-02
  0.1795000E+03  0.8424140E-01  0.1337869E-01  0.4219976E-01  0.9083083E-02  0.1498218E-01  0.7200749E-01
```

Comment: please share at least an excerpt of you data

Comment: please use triple backticks ``` to write code in posts. I edited it for you. So IIUC you have 4 header-columns for 7 data columns?

Comment: I think you mean columns, not rows.

Comment: maybe skip header - `read_csv` has option to skip some lines.

Comment: example data looks like created with `numpy` so maybe use `numpy` to read it

Comment: Reading it in as `numpy` rather than via `pandas` seemed to do the trick! Thanks for everyone's help with both the issue and general coding etiquette. Hopefully won't feel so amateur at it for too long...